# Write and save select statement data in xml

Tags: sql, xml

Can anyone help me in SQL  if it's possible to write xml file of any select statement data and save it in local drive .

Case :_

```
Select * from tableName for xml auto
```

This generates the xml file but I want to save it in the local drive ie.( the C drive or the D drive)

Will truly appreciate.  :)

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server or SQLite? These are all completely different products. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using, not just a bunch of random ones.

Comment: you would need to BCP it to export it (or an equivalent if not using SQL server - that' why the RDBMS is important

Comment: XML AUTO is not available in mysql so I assume you mean sqlserver.

Comment: Yes in SQL server